# Making animations using gganimate: im not getting it right

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to make an COVID animation using the COVID data from my country.
But i keep getting it wrong, and most of the issues i have no idea of how can i solve the problem.

```
libraries:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(ggmap)
library(tmap)
require(sp)
library(geobr)
library(readr)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)
```

First of all, you can get the dataframe from here:

```
caso <- readr::read_csv("https://data.brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso.csv.gz")
caso$date <- as.Date(caso$date)
caso$state <- as.factor(caso$state)
tibble [399,497 x 12] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date                          : Date[1:399497], format: "2020-07-22" "2020-07-21" "2020-07-20" ...
 $ state                         : Factor w/ 27 levels "AC","AL","AM",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ city                          : chr [1:399497] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ place_type                    : chr [1:399497] "state" "state" "state" "state" ...
 $ confirmed                     : num [1:399497] 34660 34405 34145 33705 33585 ...
 $ deaths                        : num [1:399497] 544 533 515 507 505 499 493 488 483 478 ...
 $ order_for_place               : num [1:399497] 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 116 115 ...
 $ is_last                       : logi [1:399497] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ estimated_population_2019     : num [1:399497] 845731 845731 845731 845731 845731 ...
 $ city_ibge_code                : num [1:399497] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ confirmed_per_100k_inhabitants: num [1:399497] 4098 4068 4037 3985 3971 ...
 $ death_rate                    : num [1:399497] 0.0157 0.0155 0.0151 0.015 0.015 0.0149 0.0149 0.01





> head(caso)
# A tibble: 6 x 12
  date       state city  place_type confirmed deaths order_for_place is_last estimated_popul~
  <date>     <fct> <chr> <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl> <lgl>              <dbl>
1 2020-07-22 AP    NA    state          34660    544             124 TRUE              845731
2 2020-07-21 AP    NA    state          34405    533             123 FALSE             845731
3 2020-07-20 AP    NA    state          34145    515             122 FALSE             845731
4 2020-07-19 AP    NA    state          33705    507             121 FALSE             845731
5 2020-07-18 AP    NA    state          33585    505             120 FALSE             845731
6 2020-07-17 AP    NA    state          33436    499             119 FALSE             845731
# ... with 3 more variables: city_ibge_code <dbl>, confirmed_per_100k_inhabitants <dbl>
```

The brazil map is also available:

```
Estados <- read_state(year=2018)
```

So far, i've been doing plots by summarizing the data,like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=ontem, aes(fill=deaths), color="#FEBF57", size=.15, show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "Mortes por COVID",size=8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "BrBG",
                       name= "Mortes Confirmadas", limits=c(min(ontem$deaths),max(ontem$deaths)))+
  theme_void() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

options(scipen=10000)
```

which results in this map:
[image: Covid Deaths - Brazil]

Where "ontem" df is a dataframe of the last day status of the covid (subset of caso):

```
ontem <- caso %>% filter(date == Sys.Date()-1,place_type == 'state')
```

But i would like to make an animation of how the deaths (for example) increase each day, i tried to use something like the same code plus  transition_time(date) but i keep getting warning/error messages.

Can someone help me with this? I'm stuck for days!

Comment: I have no access to the data, can you paste a part of it using `dput()`. in additon mention all packages and own functions in your question.

Comment: Hello, check it out now. I'm not using any functions of my own, just ggplot

Comment: sorry, but there is missing a lot. Where is `ontem`? Please check all provided code for reproducibility before posting. Where is your gganimate code?

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: and I'm pretty sure that we have not to install all of the provided packages to get this done. Please revise. I will not install all of these.

Comment: when I copy paste your data below the `head(caso)` and then run the ggplot, will it work? Pretty sure NOT

Answer (score 1):

The `transition_time()` function requires a vector to be in a date or time format.  So, you must either ensure that your time variable is in a format that `gganimate` likes (it is pretty finicky with date formats) OR you could compute an integer that tracks **sequence** of time (1, 2, 3, 4...) after sorting by date/time, and using `transition_states()` with the sequence vector.  The latter approach, I've found, is a lot easier.

Comment: To use transition_time, the argument must be ordered?
Say i have a vector c(1,3,6,4,2,5) instead of c(1,2,3,4,5,6)... will this mess up things?

Comment: I recommend you use `transition_states()` with a sequence variable equal to the order of records by date.  So, sort your records by date, then create the variable like this:  `covid_seq<-rownames(caso)`